# How to pass 3d int* pointer array to function and check if full?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

i have this 3d array that i like to pass by pointer or array to function that will check if the 3nth demotion has element , 
here is my array :

```
LevelsArray = new int**[LEVELS_COUNT];
  for (int i = 0; i < LEVELS_COUNT; ++i) 
  {
        LevelsArray[i] = new int*[MAX_ROW];  
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_ROW; ++j)
        {
              LevelsArray[i][j] = new int[MAX_CELL];

              for(int z =0;z < MAX_CELL; ++z)
              {
                  LevelsArray[i][j][z] = 1;

              }
        }
  }
```

now when i try to check its length it allways gives me 1

when i try :

```
(sizeof((LevelsArray))/sizeof((LevelsArray[0][0])))
```

2 questions here
1. how to check the LevelsArray[0][0] length ?
2. how to pass this 3d array to function that checks the array[][] length

Comment: `LevelsArray` is a pointer and `sizeof(LevelsArray)` will give you `sizeof(pointer)` not `sizeof(array)` so you need to keep count of number of elements in the array separately

Comment: The ratio of the size of two pointers is 1.  You can't check the length of `LevelsArray[0][0]`; you have to know what the length is.  You can't pass the 3D array to a function for the function to check it; you will have to tell the function the dimensions of the array.  It would help if you showed the declaration of `LevelsArray`; I'm assuming it is `int ***LevelsArray;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ and C arrays are very simple; they don't know about their size and decay into a pointer when passed to a function. (Or they are already represented by a pointer when the memory is allocated on the heap with `new` or `malloc` - that's why your `sizeof`-code evaluates the array size as 1.)

If you want to use simple C++ arrays, you must either pass the dimension explicitly or define a sentinel value as C-style strings do with the terminating `'\0'`. It might be a good idea to wrap the array in a `struct` that keeps track of the dimensions, e.g.:

```
struct {
    size_t dim1, dim2, dim3;
    int*** data;
}
```

where you can write  a constructor and a destructor for the memory management.